# How do I create my own rules in Jena Fuseki from string content?

Tags: jena, fuseki, jena-rules

I am trying to create my own property rules in Jena Fuseki. To do so I am using the `Generic Rule Reasoning` that allows me to use my own rules. When I use this strategy with my rules from a file everything works fine:

```
:model_inf a ja:InfModel ; 
    ja:baseModel :tdbGraph ; 
    ja:reasoner [ 
        ja:reasonerURL <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2003/GenericRuleReasoner> ; 
        ja:rulesFrom <file://...> ;
    ] .
```

However, I would not want to use a file but add the rules directly as a string. I tried just to copy the content of the rule files that worked in the example above, for instance (a small slice of the file):

```
#-*-mode: conf-unix-*-
@prefix time: <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#>
@include <owlmicro>

-> table(owl:sameAs).

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Equality
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sameAs_symmetry:
(?x owl:sameAs ?y)
-> (?y owl:sameAs ?x).

sameAs_transitivity:
(?x owl:sameAs ?y)
(?y owl:sameAs ?z)
-> (?x owl:sameAs ?x).

sameAs_Thing1:
-> [(?x rdf:type owl:Thing) <- (?x owl:sameAs ?y)].

sameAs_Thing2:
-> [(?x owl:sameAs ?x) <- (?x rdf:type owl:Thing)].
```

and put this in a variable `string_rules_variable` (with proper escaping):

```
:model_inf a ja:InfModel ; 
    ja:baseModel :tdbGraph ; 
    ja:reasoner [ 
        ja:reasonerURL <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2003/GenericRuleReasoner> ; 
        ja:rules [
            ${string_rules_variable}
        ] ;
    ] .
```

where ${string_rules_variable} (javascript string interpolation) contains the rules read from the file.

In the end, the repository was created with no error, but the rules doesn't worked nor the `owlmicro` statements appeared in the repository.

So, am I doing anything wrong, or is it a Jena Fuseki issue?

P.S. I am using nodejs to send this in the body of a `post` request with `text/turtle` content-type in headers.